# error al abrir un server de forge module java.base does not export sun.security.util to unnamed module

Tags: java, java-17, forge

Quiero lanzar un server de un server de forge 1.16.5

Cuando ejecuto:

```
C:\Users\Maria Cristina\OneDrive\Documentos\server forge 1.16.5>java -Xmx10G -Xms10G -jar forge-1.16.5-36.2.39.jar nogui
```

Recibo el siguiente error:

> 2023-10-16 22:43:43,758 main WARN Advanced terminal features are not available in this environment
> [22:43:43] [main/INFO] [cp.mo.mo.Launcher/MODLAUNCHER]: ModLauncher running: args [--gameDir, ., --launchTarget, fmlserver, --fml.forgeVersion, 36.2.39, --fml.mcpVersion, 20210115.111550, --fml.mcVersion, 1.16.5, --fml.forgeGroup, net.minecraftforge, nogui]
> [22:43:43] [main/INFO] [cp.mo.mo.Launcher/MODLAUNCHER]: ModLauncher 8.1.3+8.1.3+main-8.1.x.c94d18ec starting: java version 17.0.8 by Oracle Corporation
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class cpw.mods.modlauncher.SecureJarHandler (in unnamed module @0x78b729e6) cannot access class sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.util to unnamed module @0x78b729e6
> at cpw.mods.modlauncher.SecureJarHandler.lambda$static$1(SecureJarHandler.java:45)
> at cpw.mods.modlauncher.api.LamdbaExceptionUtils.uncheck(LamdbaExceptionUtils.java:95)
> at cpw.mods.modlauncher.SecureJarHandler.(SecureJarHandler.java:45)
> at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.lambda$new$6(Launcher.java:55)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
> at cpw.mods.modlauncher.api.TypesafeMap.computeIfAbsent(TypesafeMap.java:52)
> at cpw.mods.modlauncher.api.TypesafeMap.computeIfAbsent(TypesafeMap.java:47)
> at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Environment.computePropertyIfAbsent(Environment.java:62)
> at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.(Launcher.java:55)
> at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:66)
> at net.minecraftforge.server.ServerMain$Runner.runLauncher(ServerMain.java:49)
> at net.minecraftforge.server.ServerMain$Runner.access$100(ServerMain.java:46)
> at net.minecraftforge.server.ServerMain.main(ServerMain.java:43)

Comment: intenta agregando `--add-exports java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED` como primer argumento y nos cuentas si con eso funciona